# timer in VB.Net does not reset as programmed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My goal is to get another sub to run after a certain amount of time has elapsed. All of this happens after the user checks a checkbox. I have a similar program that uses the same technique and it works just fine.

However, it won't detect that the timer is a negative number. It just keeps going.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    Private Sub dataRecall()

        MsgBox("Pass")

    End Sub

    Private Sub liveViewTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles liveViewTimer.Tick

        If realTimeTimer <= 10 Then
            realTimeTimer -= 1
        ElseIf realTimeTimer = 0 Then
            realTimeTimer = 10
            dataRecall()
        End If


    End Sub

    Private Sub liveViewCheck_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles liveViewCheck.CheckedChanged
        If liveViewCheck.Checked = True Then
            liveViewTimer.Start()
        ElseIf liveViewCheck.Checked = False Then
            liveViewTimer.Stop()
            realTimeTimer = 10
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is supposed to be true once it reaches 0.

Comment: Just make it an If instead of an ElseIf.

Comment: It worked, but not really the most desirable outcome. Thank you.

Comment: What's not right with it?

Comment: Using it all in the same if statement should have worked, especially since I have done this before with no issues. I'm going to post it as the answer and revisit this if it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the intended code is more like:

```
Private Sub dataRecall()

    MsgBox("Pass")

End Sub

Private Sub liveViewTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If realTimeTimer <= 10 Then
        realTimeTimer -= 1
    End If

    If realTimeTimer = 0 Then
        realTimeTimer = 10
        dataRecall()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub liveViewCheck_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles liveViewCheck.CheckedChanged
    If liveViewCheck.Checked = True Then
        realTimeTimer = 10
        liveViewTimer.Start()
    Else
        liveViewTimer.Stop()
    End If

End Sub
```

So that when the checkbox is checked, `dataRecall` is called ten seconds (or whatever) later and every ten seconds after that.

Comment: The ```dataRecall()``` sub is supposed to be continuous, so the timer must not stop once it reaches zero.

Comment: @VeneerLarry Ah, understood. I've edited my answer accordingly.